# solrj: Search for words with whitepaces

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to search for eg:"project launch". I am replacing whitepace with "/ ". This works properly when I query directly from solr. But it doesnt work when called from solrj. Please help!

Comment: SolrJ does HTML encoding. Just use `solrQuery.setQuery("project launch")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user entered a search query with the phrase "project launch" (with quotes), then you can use [ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.html#escapeQueryChars%28java.lang.String%29) to escape the quotes with Solrj:

```
String q = "\"project launch\"";
q = ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(q);
```

Note that this will escape all the Lucene [special characters used in query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html?is-external=true#Escaping_Special_Characters). If you want more control over what special (query syntax) characters are allowed in your queries, then create your own copy of this function and modify accordingly.